# Phabricator conduit.connect C# Certificate Error

Tags: c#, phabricator, conduit

I am trying to write an interface to our Phabricator install to allow out internal improvement system to create tasks.  However, I cannot figure out why I keep getting a certificate error.

```
"{\"result\":null,\"error_code\":\"ERR-INVALID-CERTIFICATE\",\"error_info\":\"Your authentication certificate for this server is invalid.\"}"
```

The following is my code;

```
    private void CreateSession()
    {
        int token = (int)((DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).TotalSeconds);

        var result = this.Do(
            "conduit.connect",
            new
            {
                client = this.ClientName,
                clientVersion = this.ClientVersion,
                clientDescription = "HIS to Fabricator Connector",
                user = this.User,
                authToken = token,
                authSignature = SHA1HashStringForUTF8String(token + this.Certificate)
            });
        this.m_SessionKey = result.sessionKey;
        this.m_ConnectionID = result.connectionID;
    }

public static string SHA1HashStringForUTF8String(string s)
    {
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s);

        var sha1 = SHA1.Create();
        byte[] hashBytes = sha1.ComputeHash(bytes);

        return HexStringFromBytes(hashBytes);
    }

public static string HexStringFromBytes(byte[] bytes)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (byte b in bytes)
        {
            var hex = b.ToString("x2");
            sb.Append(hex);
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

This returns the following JSON;

```
"{\"client\":\"HIS\",\"clientVersion\":\"1\",\"clientDescription\":\"HIS to Fabricator Connector\",\"user\":\"KYLIE\",\"authToken\":1449486922,\"authSignature\":\"ec020edbd5082d3971c2c11ef4f4917244fc4a78\"}"
```

I think the issue is the certificate I am passing.  I am using;

```
api-3ydcae2gtmf6u6uer2zow465j6px
```

which I obtained from the Conduit API Tokens page.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 1):

1. You have to get the token via .../conduit/token
2. Use that token to query .../api/conduit.getcertificate

As result you get the certificate -> profit! :)

PS: it's neither api- nor cli- token to query the certificate! ;)